# change value in two columns based on two other columns

Tags: vba, excel

i have pieced together this code to change value in two cells based on two other cells.  how do i get this code to apply to the entire column ranges?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If Range("N6").Value Like "FINISH" And Not Range("CL6").Value Like "BK WALL" Or Not Range("CL6").Value Like "INTG" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("CH6").Value = "Y"
End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
   If Not Range("N6").Value Like "FINISH" Or Range("CL6").Value Like "BK WALL" Or Range("CL6").Value Like "INTG" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("CH6").Value = "X"
        Range("CO6").Value = ""
End If

ErrorExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
    Resume ErrorExit
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler


End Sub
```

Comment: *how do i get this code to apply to the entire column ranges* - can you be more specific?

Comment: I think (I am not a mind-reader) that you want to apply the code to the entire Columm N (and Columns "CH" ...). Just use a `For lRow = 6 to LastRow` , and then `If Range("N" & lRow).Value Like "FINISH" ...` , you can figure out the rest

Comment: sorry for not being specific.  i'm new to vba.i'm trying to get the code to apply to the column range

Comment: sorry for not being specific.  i'm new to vba.i'm trying to get the code to apply to the column range N6:N45 and the adjacent cells in columns CH,CL and CO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim dStart As Double, dFinish As Double, d As Double

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

dStart = 6
dFinish = Range("N" & dStart).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + dStart - 1
'You could just hard-code in dFinish = 45 here if you want...


For d = dStart To dFinish

    If Range("N" & d).Value Like "FINISH" And Not Range("CL" & d).Value Like "BK WALL" Or Not Range("CL6").Value Like "INTG" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("CH" & d).Value = "Y"
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    If Not Range("N" & d).Value Like "FINISH" Or Range("CL" & d).Value Like "BK WALL" Or Range("CL" & d).Value Like "INTG" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("CH" & d).Value = "X"
        Range("CO" & d).Value = ""
    End If

Next

ErrorExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
    Resume ErrorExit
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler


End Sub
```

Comment: the code seems to work, but it freezes the entire sheet for a few minutes whenever i enter data anywhere else.

Comment: Well yes, by using the Worksheet_Change event any time you change anything this will fire. If you want to only make this do something every time you change one of the cells you're after then you'll have to change `d` to be `Target.Row` rather than looping and you could also test the column etc.

Comment: i changed d to be target.row ,but now i get a compile error.

Comment: @IDesp the way Tim meant to trap the Column modified, is let's say you only want the code to run if someone modified anything in Column N, then add in the beginning of the code the line `If Target.Column <> 14 Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile now but if you don't get it by the morning I'll edit it for you.

Comment: @Shai Rado...that line of code seems to cancel out the changes in column CL, but now the value in column CH changes repeatedly from "x" to "y" for a few minutes before settling on a value.  and if the values in column CL or CO changes manually then code doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Tim Edwards...its all good.  your help has taken one step closer to what i need and is very much appreciated.

Comment: @IDesp what columns do you want to scan and apply these changes for ?

Comment: the parameters in column N and CL are dropdown selections that can be changed manually.  column CH is hidden and used to lockout the dropdown selection column CO.

Comment: Do you still need help or have you got it sorted now?

Comment: I changed my approach a bit by hard coding the value of column CH into each cell.  since your code works, i modified it to only change the value of column CO from the value in CH. it runs a little smoother since excel only has to look at one column instead of three to produce the final result.  thanks a million for your help...i'm new to vba and couldn't have done it without you and Shai.